# Need a tablet or smart note pad interface for medical physician

Tags: tablet, touchscreen, touchpad

I am seeking a tablet or smart note taking pad that I can use to integrate with a database for a medical centre.

The scenario is basically digitalising a doctor's office.
 When the doctor interviews the patients, he would like to have a tablet or smart interface with note taking options and drawing features digitally. And have the outcomes saved unto a database. It directly involves software as well.

But I would like to know if there are any dedicated products that have already been established for this purpose? I have taken a look at WACOM products.. but additional recommendations are welcomed.

Comment: I think something important to consider here is what Electronic Health Record software you're going to be using on this tablet, if any. You could look for reviews specific to your EHR or even contact their support team to see if they have any recommendations. For what it's worth, an MS Surface Pro would easily fit your needs; your final decision will come down to whether or not you can find something suitable at a better price and if those tradeoffs will be worth it long-term. A used (slightly older) Surface model might do the trick as well.

Comment: Thanks @jcam3
Well we are in the process of setting up a data base also. So will actually contact these providers as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A Surface Pro may be good. I cant say I've ever used one myself but they're full Windows 10 so I guess it'd be easier to integrate? Only issue if they're a tad expensive...

Comment: Thanks @Max... I agree with you on the price though...